# Working of short circuit and unary operator

Tags: java, operator-precedence

Please have a look at the following code:

```
int i=5;
boolean b = i<5 && ++i<5;//line 2
System.out.println(i);//line 3, prints 5
```

In line 2, according to my understanding: Since among all the operators, ++ has highest precedence `++i` should be evaluated first. But `line 3` actually is printing `i=5` (and not `6`). Meaning, && has evaluated before ++ operator. How is it possible?

EDIT: From the answers I see that "In Java, all expressions are evaluated from left to right.". **But when does actually precedence order comes into play**. In following code:

```
int a=1,b=1,c=1;
boolean b = a==b&&b==c;//Line2
```

In line2 code would't just run from left to right. First a==b is evaluated then b==c and then && operator. Can you please explain more?

Comment: expressions are evaluated from left to right - only then, operator precedence is used to group the "subresults".

Comment: Don't confuse operator precedence with evaluation order. They are different things.

Comment: By the way, evaluation order doesn't only come into play with short-circuiting operators, but with others too. Consider `int n = 5; System.out.println(++n + --n*1000);`

Answer (score 7):

That's not how the expression is processed.

In Java, *all* expressions are evaluated from left to right. *Operator precedence* only comes into play when considering the evaluation of the *arguments* of `&&`.

So `i < 5` is computed before `++i < 5` is even considered.

In this case `++i < 5` *will* **not** be evaluated, since `i < 5` is `false`. So `i` stays at `5`.

Comment: Hi. I have just made an edit. Could you please answer that too. Thanks!

Comment: As that's fundamentally a new question, you ought to ask it as such, and roll back the question edit. (Otherwise you invalidate all the current answers.) I'll look out for it.

Answer (score 1):

The key is: ++ has the highest precedence inside a expression, but the sentence `boolean b = i<5 && ++i<5` has two expressions evaluated from left to right.

Think of `b = i<5 && ++i<5` like:

```
if( i<5 ){
  if ( ++i<5 ){
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I have just made an edit. Could you please answer that too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your misunderstanding is in how the '&&' works. When you use them java uses short circuit or lazy evaluation.

`boolean equal = 1==1 && 1==2` java evaluates the `1==1` sees it as `true`, checks the ampersands and has to evaluate the `1==2` which is `false` and therefore `equal` is `false`.

`boolean equal = 1==2 && 1==1` java evaluates the `1==2` sees it as false, then checks the ampersands and can see that whether the next expression is true or false the outcome is the same, that `equal` is `false`. Therefor it never evaluates the second equation.

More plainly the second example is saying `boolean equal = false & true`. This can only be true if both are true. Thus knowing the first is false is all we need to know the outcome. By ignoring the sencond expression at this point we can save needless calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your edited answer, the second code snippet also evaluates from left to right.

In both cases there is an expression of the form `A && B` with `A` as the left argument and `B` as the right argument of `&&`.

Here is where "left-to-right" applies. First, the left expression `A` is evaluated. In your first code snippet, that is `i<5` and since this expression evaluates to `false`, the second argument to that isn't even considered, since the whole expression will evaluate to `false` (short-circuiting).

In your second snippet you have as left argument `a==b`. Since that evaluates to `true`, only now the second argument is considered, which also evaluates to `true`. That leaves you with `true && true` which can then be processed further.

Comment: I still dont understand. Feel like dumb. What makes b==c second argument? Why can't I have b&&b==c as second argument as
:a==(b&&b==c) or something similar? Why just  (a==b)&&(b==c) ?

Comment: It's `(a==b)&&(b==c)` because of Java's operator precedence. `==` has a higher precedence than `&&`. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html