# Deciding the order in which operators will operate

Tags: java, operator-precedence

While deciding the order in which operators will operate, I am confused between following two statement.

1. Statement will be executed from left to right.
2. It will be executed according to precedence order of operators.

Following code executes from left to right

```
int i=5;    
boolean b = i<5 && ++i<5;//line2
System.out.println(i);//prints 5
//left to right execution in line2.
//< is executed and ++ is not.Even though ++ has higher precedence.
```

But this code below seems to follow precedence order:

```
int a=1,b=1,c=1;
boolean b = a==b&&b==c;//line2: (a==b)&&(b==c) 
 /*   In line2 code would not run from left to right. 
First a==b is evaluated then b==c and then && operator.*/
```

I have asked partially this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39852128/working-of-short-circuit-and-unary-operator) but did't get good enough explanation.
Can someone please clarify?

Comment: The sub-results are evaluated left-to-right. I believe thats a response you got on the previous question

Answer (score 0):

Assignment works from right to left. In your case, the `boolean b` will be assigned to whatever the expression on the right evaluates to:

```
a==b&&b==c
```

Note that assignment operators have different rules than logical/bitwise operators in terms of precedence (i.e. `=` doesn't have the same precedence as `==` or `&&`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to know about logical AND and OR.

`something && somethingElse` - imagine that expression. It's gonna return true ONLY if both values are true. If both are false, or one of them is false - returns false. So, let's say that the first part is actually false (`something=false`). Like I said, if anything in this expression is false then there is no need to go further, because no matter what is the second one it's gonna return false anyway. That's why in your first example it doesn't go any further - there is no need, `i` is already not less than `5` so there is no reason to check the second part, because it's already gonna be false.

In your second example `a==b` is true, BUT we can't return true already, we need to check the second one, because like I said, if the second one is false then it has to return false. So the expression needs to go further to check the second part. Not like in first example where we could stop, here we need to keep checking.

When it comes to OR (`||`) rules are different. Only one of the parts needs to be true (that's why it's called or, this or that, doesn't matter, one truth is enough). So with `||` if the first part is true the we can return no matter what, but if the first part is false then we need to keep going no matter what, because the second one may be true.

Answer (score 0):

```
i<5 && ++i<5;//line2
```

1. &&
2. [&&] eval LHS: i<5 to false
3. [&&] skip RHS: ++i<5 and yield false

And 
//line2: (a==b)&&(b==c)

```
a==b&&b==c;
```

1. &&
2. [&&] eval LHS: a==b to true
3. [&&] eval RHS: b==c to true, yield true

The `&&` is a short-cut operator that does not evaluate the right hand side.

The precedences are important for binary operators. The precedence of unary operators cannot reorder anything, but traditionally it has higher precedence, as it is tighter bound to the final value, and especially for postfix operators.

The prefix operator `++` has the important characteristic, that it is called before the evaluation of the term to which it is applied.

It goes without say, that the usage above is something to be get shot for, hung on the nearest AVL tree, tiered and feathered and chased out of town.